# Where to place Schema.org markup code in index.html page?

Tags: html, schema.org, rich-snippets

I have created Schema.org code using schema.creator site for my local business and my products. I want this code to use in my company website. I have couple of questions on this:

- Is it fine to paste this code in my index.html page?
- Where exactly do I need to paste this code in the HTML page? I tried to paste it under `head`, and the content is directly displaying in the browser.
- I have created the code to get Rich Snippet. Is it correct way to create Rich Snippet?

Comment: You should include a small example of the generated code in your question.

Comment: micro data attributes should either go directly onto the tags on the page - eg if you had a product page and the h1 for that page was product title, you would add the schema tags to the h1; or they should go within the relevant sections as meta tags.  See this for an example: http://schema-creator.org/product.php

Answer (score 0):

Schema tags should be inside the body tag.

I do not use a generator but always look at [schema.org](http://schema.org) as reference and validate them with [Google testing tool](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/).